# How do I start a regicide game?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-de

I'm playing *Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition*, and in the event "Women of History," the last challenge is to "Play a Regicide game." I know that a regicide game is a game in which you have a king that you need to keep safe, but how do I even start playing one? I have been looking through the various menus in the game, as well as tried to google how to just launch such a game, but I have had no luck.

How do I start playing a regicide game, so that I can check off this very mysterious challenge from the event? (I didn't think that the difficulty in this challenge would lie in figuring out how to use the game menus!)

Answer (score 6):

You want *"Game Mode"* drop down list in the *Single Player* → *Skirmish* (or *Multiplayer* → *Host Game*) screen. You will see a bunch of different game modes, *Regicide* is among them:

[image]